# Searching of listview item on Action bar

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello I'm a newbie in android studio. I want to do searching of `ListView` item on action bar without using database. Currently my code only show the `ListView` with multiple lines of text. Can you help me achieve this using search widget instead of editText?

Answer (score 4):

**1. Add search menu**

Create a menu resource file with search menu item(when click on search menu item, search widget will be appear in action bar). 
Following is an example menu resource that I have created(res/menu/search_menu.xml)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

In above menu item the collapseActionView attribute allows your SearchView to expand to take up the whole action bar and collapse back down into a normal action bar item when not in use

**2. Create SearchableConfiguration**

Searchable Configuration defines how SearchView behaves
Need to define it in a xml(res/xml/searchable.xml). Following is an example searchable configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="Search friend">
</searchable>
```

Then add this element into a relevant activity with  tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.FriendListActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Yello"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.SensorDetailsActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable">
    </meta-data>
</activity>
```

In my scenario I'm gonna add SearchView to FriendListActivity

**3. Add Menu and SearchableConfiguration to activity**

Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView in the activity class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
                            getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}
```

Now the SearchView added to the activity. But still searching functionality not working

**4. Add searching functionality**

Implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` in activity, need to override two new methods now

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
```

This interface listen to text change events in SearchView

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    friendListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

    return true;
}
```

In here onQueryTextChange function do the filtering with list adapter, In order to do the filtering, adapter need to be implement Filterable interface

**4.Filterable adapter**

In my scenario I have used BaseAdapter with implementing Filterable interface 
Following is the implementation of my adapter class(FriendListAdapter)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import com.score.senzors.R;
import com.score.senzors.pojos.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Display friend list
 *
 */
public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private FriendListActivity activity;
private FriendFilter friendFilter;
private Typeface typeface;
private ArrayList<User> friendList;
private ArrayList<User> filteredList;

/**
 * Initialize context variables
 * @param activity friend list activity
 * @param friendList friend list
 */
public FriendListAdapter(FriendListActivity activity, ArrayList<User> friendList) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.friendList = friendList;
    this.filteredList = friendList;
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/vegur_2.otf");

    getFilter();
}

/**
 * Get size of user list
 * @return userList size
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredList.size();
}

/**
 * Get specific item from user list
 * @param i item index
 * @return list item
 */
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return filteredList.get(i);
}

/**
 * Get user list item id
 * @param i item index
 * @return current item id
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

/**
 * Create list row view
 * @param position index
 * @param view current list item view
 * @param parent parent
 * @return view
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
    // to findViewById() on each row.
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final User user = (User) getItem(position);

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_row_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iconText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_list_row_layout_name);
        holder.iconText.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.iconText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        holder.name.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // get view holder back
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // bind text with view holder content view for efficient use
    holder.iconText.setText("#");
    holder.name.setText(user.getEmail());
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.friend_list_selector);

    return view;
}

/**
 * Get custom filter
 * @return filter
 */
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (friendFilter == null) {
        friendFilter = new FriendFilter();
    }

    return friendFilter;
}

/**
 * Keep reference to children view to avoid unnecessary calls
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView iconText;
    TextView name;
}

/**
 * Custom filter for friend list
 * Filter content in friend list according to the search text
 */
private class FriendFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0) {
            ArrayList<User> tempList = new ArrayList<User>();

            // search content in friend list
            for (User user : friendList) {
                if (user.getEmail().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempList.add(user);
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = friendList.size();
            filterResults.values = friendList;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    /**
     * Notify about filtered list to ui
     * @param constraint text
     * @param results filtered result
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredList = (ArrayList<User>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```

In here I have defined custom Filter class FriendFilter to do the filtering, I'm filtering the list according to the name entering in SearchView

Comment: filterable adapter on new activity?

Comment: You can customize your custom adapter to `class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable`

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoTextView

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.your_autotext_view);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);

private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"};
```

If you do not understand this code refere to this [AutoTextView Example](http://www.journaldev.com/9574/android-autocompletetextview-example-tutorial)

Comment: i want to do searching of listview item on action  bar :)

Comment: put the strings you want to be searched in AutoTextView adapter instead of "COUNTRIES"

Comment: is it same with searching on action bar?

Comment: I used it in Toolbar, I do not know if it works on action bar

Answer (score 0):

### CREATE EDIT TEXT IN YOUR LAYOUT

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search products.."
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```

### Declare your edit text in your java code

inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

> Enabling Search Filter

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }
     
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         
    }
     
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```

> IF YOU HAVE ANY TROUBLES YOU CAN REFER TO THIS [LINK](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Comment: Do you mean i need to create new layout tht contain edit text?

Comment: Just create Edit text in your current layout

Comment: is this the same with searching on action bar?

Comment: yes definitely, instead of EditText, user your own action bar

Comment: is the same if I use search widget?

Comment: already try but its not working. symbol addTextChangedListener cannot be resolve